# How to suppress [PowerShell] unable to find type [typename] message

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm writing PowerShell in VSCode. I have a module that has a class in it, then I am using that class in a script that has using at the top.

```
#Requires -Version 5
using module VrVsts
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
class VegaConfig
{
    [PSObject] $Project
    [PSObject] $User

    VegaConfig() {
        . "$PSScriptRoot\Get-UserPreferences.ps1"

        $this.project = [PSCustomObject](Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\ProjectConfig.json" | ConvertFrom-Json)
        $this.user = Get-UserPreferences -RegistrySubfolder $this.project.UserPreferencesRegistryPath
    }
    [Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("TypeNotFound", "", Target='VstsConnection', Justification='Parser Not good enough to detect this')]

#** Warnings are here
    [VstsConnection] VstsConnection() {
        return ([VstsConnection]::New($this.project.VstsUrl, $this.user.Credential))
    }
}
```

It works fine but the warning is annoying as it makes my file red and could hide other legitimate problems with the file. The warning is:

> [PowerShell] unable to find type [VstsConnection]
>   [PSScriptAnalyzer] Ignoring 'TypeNotFound' parse error on type 'VstsConnection'. Check if the specified type is correct. This can also be due the type not being known at parse time due to typed imported by 'using' statements

Any ideas on how I can suppress this? I tried with SuppressMessageAttribute as shown but this doesn't seem to do anything. I know that this works with specific PSScriptAnalyzer cases but it hasn't actually removed either the PowerShell message or the PSScriptAnalyzer warning.

Comment: Classes get parsed before everything else.  You need to have the type loaded in the session before using it or you will continue to have an exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the type at the beginning of the script itself.

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this as well, doesn't matter where I put SuppressMessage I can't get rid of that message.
I think it's a bug as I've already imported the module containing class yet vs code complains it can't find the type.