# Really, how do you suppress PowerShell analyzer rules

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-core

The MS docs are here: [supressing rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/using-scriptanalyzer?view=ps-modules#suppressing-rules) but it really doesn't work as documented when using VS Code. I have the following at the top of my script:

```
# Supress some analyzer (linter) diagnostics:
[Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute('PSAvoidUsingCmdletAliases','')]
```

But, the analyzer itself is complaining about that statement, "Unexpected attribute". Looks like this:

[image: error expanded]

And, who wants to see all this red!

[image: unexpanded]

Interestingly, when I add a second, similar statement, like this:

```
# Supress some analyzer (linter) diagnostics:
[Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute('PSProvideCommentHelp','')]
[Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute('PSAvoidUsingCmdletAliases','')]
```

The first statement is no longer flagged as an error, just the second one is.

But, the bottom line is my attempt to suppress the messages is not working.

I read over the .NET docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute?view=net-7.0)

I even tried adding

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll'
```

As suggested in an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918645/how-to-suppress-powershell-unable-to-find-type-typename-message), but that made no difference.

I am on PS Core 7.3.7, on Windows 10 Pro with .NET 7.0.5. And VS Code 1.82.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you're trying to use the decoration outside the context it is supposed to be used in, you need to use it to decorate a `param` block. See [**Suppressing Rules**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/using-scriptanalyzer?view=ps-modules#suppressing-rules).

A simple example, before suppression:

[image: before]

And after:

[image: after]

And, if I remove the `param` block, I get exactly the same parsing error:

[image: error]

---

For your specific use case, for suppressing the [`PSAvoidUsingCmdletAliases` rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/rules/avoidusingcmdletaliases?view=ps-modules) and following what's stated above, you can use a dummy `param()` at the top of your script file and it should work properly:

[image]